# Unable to Run Excel VBA code on citrix on excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code which is working on Windows machine on VM, but same code giving error in citrix environment, both excel version are same 2013. 
I have a "collection" object which is giving error, "invalid procedure call or argument", any help much apricated.

I make sync of all properties on both environment excel.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the code?

Comment: Please read [ask]  then search for your error msg (include keyword collection)!

Comment: Public Property Get extraparam(index As Integer) As Collection 
    Set extraparam = extraparams(index)  
End Property  

Public Property Get extra_params() As Collection()  
    If IsEmpty(extraparams) Then  
        extra_params = Collection  
    Else  
        extra_params = extraparams  
    End If  
    
End Property  

Public Property Let extraparam(index As Integer, MyValue As Collection)  
    ReDim Preserve extraparams(index)  
    Set extraparams(index) = MyValue  
End Property